# Triggering clearIconTap callback on dynamically created fields

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am creating a simple app using Sencha Touch where I'm  dynamically creating container with `textfield`s, `textareafield`s etc. when the user needs to add new container with components. The problem now is when the clear icon on the `textareafield` is tapped it clears the text, but I would like to know which `textareafield` has been cleared. Can anyone help me in this please?

This is how I created container .

```
    var childObj2 = {};
    childObj2.xtype = 'container';

    var type = 'vbox';
    var layout = {}
    layout.type = type;
    childObj1.layout = layout;

    var txtarea= {};
    txtarea.xtype = 'textareafield';
    txtarea.id = "txt51";
    txtarea.flex = 3;
    txtarea.maxRows = 7;
    txtarea.placeHolder = 'Type here';
    txtarea.value = value['notes'];
    txtarea.inputCls = 'txtareaStyle'
    txtarea.clearicontap = "clearText";

How to add clearicontap listener to this?
```

Comment: Your coding pattern is very odd according to sencha standards. Inspite can you tell me, if you are using any controller file or not?

Comment: Yes am using MVC pattern advised by Secnha touch. Still I wanna try out every others ways, say like using store model to access websql or use direct sql query to access websql. I am new to Sencha touch so am getting used to MVC and non MVC stlye of coding for mu understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you you create a `textfield` simply add a listener to it for the `clearicontap` event and that callback will get executed for each of the fields.

For example:

```
var container = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {});

for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    var field = Ext.create('Ext.field.Text', {
        id: 'textfieldnumber' + i,
        listeners: {
            clearicontap: function() {
                alert("Tapped clear icon on text field number: " + i + "!");
            }
        }
    });
    container.add(field);
}
```

[EDIT]

I answer the question you make after your edit:

I am using the standard way of creating Sencha components through `Ext.create()`, and I would suggest you to switch to the same way. It is not clear by the code you posted how those Javascript objects are actually transformed into `Ext` components. Anyway, they are very likely components configurations, so I guess you could try:

```
txtarea.listeners = {
    clearicontap: function() {
        alert("Tapped clear icon on text field");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question. Please check that and help me if u can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really helped me. Previously I tried something like this with listener but somewhere I made mistake. So clearicontap was called even while creating the view. Now it works correct. Thanks for your time to help me.